# First-price sealed-bid auction with information advantage

Tags: probability, game-theory, nash-equilibrium, auction-theory

Consider two bidders $A$ and $B$ bidding for a box of 10 coins. The auction is performed in a first-price sealed-bid manner. The winner gets $k$ dollars if there are $k$ heads in the box. The probability for each coin to be head is $1/2$. Obviously, both $A$ and $B$ know the fair value of the box is 5 dollars so both $A$ and $B$ bidding 5 dollars is a pure strategy Nash equilibrium.

Now consider a twist. Assume $A$ has the advantage to see whether the first five coins in the box are heads or not. $B$ cannot see the coins but knows $A$ can see. They then both bid once in a first-price sealed-bid manner for the box.

My question is what the Nash equilibrium is for the second game, if there exists any? I think there does not exist any pure strategy Nash equilibrium but I don't know how to find the mixed strategy Nash equilibrium.

Comment: What happens when the bids are tied?

Comment: Let's assume the money goes to each winner with equal probability. Or we can assume the money always goes to A or B if that makes the problem easier.

Comment: And who pays?$ $

Comment: I don't get the last question. Why is it relevant?

Comment: Well, because the players' payoff depends on whether they have to pay their bid or not. E.g. if ties were resolved by both players paying their bid but only one of them getting the money (with equal probability), then each player bidding $5$ dollars wouldn't be a Nash equilibrium in the first game.

Comment: You are right. Let us assume whoever gets the money pays the bid.